# How to concatenate strings in windows batch file for loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm familiar with Unix shell scripting, but new to windows scripting.

I have a list of strings containing str1, str2, str3...str10. I want to do like this:

```
for string in string_list
do
  var = string+"xyz"
  svn co var
end
```

I do found some thread describing how to concatenate string in batch file. But it somehow doesn't work in for loop. So I'm still confusing about the batch syntax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to concatenate variable with string or variable in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349027/how-to-concatenate-variable-with-string-or-variable-in-batch-file)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In batch you could do it like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "string_list=str1 str2 str3 ... str10"

for %%s in (%string_list%) do (
  set "var=%%sxyz"
  svn co "!var!"
)
```

If you don't need the variable `!var!` elsewhere in the loop, you could simplify that to

```
@echo off

setlocal

set "string_list=str1 str2 str3 ... str10"

for %%s in (%string_list%) do svn co "%%sxyz"
```

However, like C.B. I'd prefer PowerShell if at all possible:

```
$string_list = 'str1', 'str2', 'str3', ... 'str10'

$string_list | ForEach-Object {
  $var = "${_}xyz"   # alternatively: $var = $_ + 'xyz'
  svn co $var
}
```

Again, this could be simplified if you don't need `$var` elsewhere in the loop:

```
$string_list = 'str1', 'str2', 'str3', ... 'str10'
$string_list | ForEach-Object { svn co "${_}xyz" }
```

Answer (score 65):

Try this, with strings:

```
set "var=string1string2string3"
```

and with string variables:

```
set "var=%string1%%string2%%string3%"
```

Comment: Hint: careful  about NO space between var and =

Comment: how about mixing strings with string variables?

Answer (score 15):

A very simple example:

```
SET a=Hello
SET b=World
SET c=%a% %b%!
echo %c%
```

The result should be:

```
Hello World!
```

Comment: If you add a more or less duplicate answer, it should at least work (It doesn't, the output is `!`)

Comment: Please try to run it via cmd, not power shell.

Comment: The question is regarding concatenating strings in a loop. Your answer does not apply within a loop? Therefore, the answer is irrelevant to the original question.