# How do i Add all Subfolders to Classpath [like -cp "lib\**\*"]

Tags: java, directory, classpath, wildcard, executable-jar

I can't find a way, to add all the **libraries** from all **Subdirectories** of a specific **Directory** inside **classpath** without having to mention each subfolder [...]

## For example, let's say i have that kind of directory hierarchy:

```
aplication_Folder:
 ⎿ App.jar
  external_libraries:
   ⎿ folder1:
     ⎿ File_1.1.jar
     ⎿ File_1.2.jar
   ⎿ folder2:
     ⎿ File_2.1.jar
     ⎿ File_2.2.jar
     ⎿ File_2.3.jar
        ...
```

How could i run my Application (App.jar) instead of selecting each SubFolder like here:

> java -cp "./App.jar;./external_libraries/folder1/*; ./external_libraries/folder2/*;" app.App

In a way like in this line:

> java -cp "./App.jar;./external_libraries/**/*;" app.App

.

## [Update] Kind of Solved :

For now i use that code *(with minor problems like, that it doesnt get Subfolders with names that have Spaces between Like "folder 3" and Sub...Subfolders)*:

```sh
   @echo off
   
   set CLASSPATH=./App.jar;
   
   for /f %%i in ('dir .\external_libraries\/b') DO (
      call :append ./external_libraries/%%i/*
   )
   
   java app.App
   goto :eof
   
   :append
      set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%%1;
```

Which populates CLASSPATH with:

> ./App.jar;./external_libraries/folder1/*;./external_libraries/folder2/*;..."

Such as, it can be used like this:

> java app.App

.

## Extra Info For Newbies like me:

You do **NOT** need to use CLASSPATH, to run the App like here:

> java -cp "%CLASSPATH%" app.App

Because When you already have set CLASSPATH's variable content, java automatically reads it (just be sure that the name of the Variable is actually 'CLASSPATH' and not anything else) see comments for more info why [...]

.

## Ending:

Any response would be really appreciated.
Thanks in Advance,
George.

Comment: I don't think you can easily; and why do you need to? You're clearly already writing a batch script to start the jar... I'd just setup the `CLASSPATH` variable and use that. `set "CLASSPATH=./App.jar;./external_libraries/folder1/*;./external_libraries/folder2/*"` and then `java app.App` - `java` will search the `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: Also, note the location of `"` in my `set` command is correct. Windows is different from everything else - where it would be `export CLASSPATH="./App.jar:./external_libraries/folder1/*:./external_libraries/folder2/*"`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i need it in that weird way, because my application uses "joor" package, which means that i compile code in Runtime and that code most probably will need to use some external libraries, which libraries will be in fact inside subfolders (for better organization)

Comment: + I know before start what libraries need to be used for the code that will be compiled in Runtime

Comment: Try it in my non-weird way... because my non-weird way works exactly the same as the way you have posted. Literally the same.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I know it works in the same way but it doesn't work in the way i want, which is without mentioning each folder (folder1, folder2 , etc.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198090/discussion-between-giorgos-xou-and-elliott-frisch).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Sorry , i had `java -cp "./App.jar;./external_libraries/folder1/**/*;" app.App` instead of `java -cp "./App.jar;./external_libraries/**/*;" app.App`

Comment: That's fine. Literally build that string as the `CLASSPATH` environment variable and you're done. No need to pass `-cp` (that overrides the `CLASSPATH`).

Comment: .-. i don't get it , if you mean to create a loop that creates an "appended" string named `CLASSPATH` and then pass it like `java -cp CLASSPATH` , i just dont know how to make that script ..

Comment: I mean no need to pass anything to or even include -cp when you set CLASSPATH. As for how, https://stackoverflow.com/q/17743757/2970947

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks for the link but actually i found out how, only that now i have that problem ["CMD Character Limit"](https://www.digizol.com/2006/12/input-line-is-too-long-windows-command.html)

Comment: Edit your question.

Comment: to what ? (forgive me but i 'm kinda newbe)

Comment: you mean to update it such as it contain that issue too?

Comment: The code and the issue. Simply saying you have a new problem, without showing the code is not particularly helpful.

Comment: Ok, i just have to do some modifications on my batch code and i will

Comment: This is "batch" code. Not bash code.

Comment: mistyping :P lol

Comment: `java -cp "%CLASSPATH%" app.App` should just be `java app.App`... as I have mentioned a few times, once you set `CLASSPATH` you no longer need to also specify `-cp` and `-cp %CLASSPATH%` is never necessary.

Comment: you are right, i 'll change it , (i didn't know that, thanks)

Comment: Once you do, that command line limit issue should be resolved.

Comment: you are right! :O , Thanks you again!

Comment: and i am sorry for being such a newbee on this line

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198102/discussion-on-question-by-giorgos-xou-how-do-i-add-all-subfolders-to-classpath).

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have two options:

- custom start script where you grab all required jars and populate classpath and pass it to -cp java param. See comments for details
- custom classloader where you application is starting having only one (root) jar in cp and then main class is determining root jar directory and then traverses subdirectories and grab all required jar then creates new class loader with grabbed jars and launch application.

Comment: Custom start script would be ideal! (just i don't know how)

Comment: I don't have exact one for your case. But I believe you can easily adjust this one for your needs: https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/8077/one-line-command-to-recursively-add-all-jar-files-in-current-folder-to-java-class-path